# Name of a misusage

Tags: catachresis

What do you call the catachresis(? or misusage)  when one uses an unreasonably extreme form of an attribute or adjective in a sentence where a more moderate one would be correct?

(e.g.there are two things to choose from and someone says "That's the best" (instead of 'the better one'); or a team have only played one match in a league but their performance so far is desrcibed as 'flawless' )

Comment: It's a form of *overstatement* or [*hyperbole*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hyperbole)

Comment: Or possibly sarcasm.

Comment: Or an exaggeration. (*Exaggeration can be a rhetorical device or figure of speech. It may be used to evoke strong feelings or to create a strong impression.*)

Answer (score 1):

The first example ("best" vs. "better") is just misuse of the comparative and superlative - it's actually breaking a generally accepted rule of grammar.

The second example is not a self-evident error; it would be possible for a bowling team to have a single flawless match.

In general, the "unreasonably extreme form of an attribute or adjective" would be *hyperbole*, exaggerating the description beyond what is true in reality.